# Show floating avatars in recyclerview items in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, telegram

I have a recyclerview of message items, which shows messages with avatars in the end left side infront of the message. If we have a multiple message sent by the same sender we showing its avatar only in the last written message. So basically - when messages are long, it would be convenient to have avatars of message authors floating vertically from the beginning of the message to its end, like in Telegram. The avatar is shown at the beginning of the message, but as you scroll down it moves to the end of the message and back again if you scroll up. If there are multiple messages, the avatar floats to the end of the user's last message.

I tried to use Sticky Header Decoration:

```
class AvatarStickyHeaderDecoration(
    private val avatarDecoratorPredicate: AvatarDecoratorPredicate
) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun onDrawOver(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state)

        val count = parent.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0
        if (count <= 1) {
            return
        }

        for (i in 0 until count - 1) {
            val headerHolder = parent.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
            val nextHolder = parent.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i + 1)

            if (headerHolder is IncomingMessageController.Holder && nextHolder is IncomingMessageController.Holder) {
                val isSameSender = avatarDecoratorPredicate.isSameSenderMessage(i, i + 1)

                if (isSameSender && headerHolder.itemView.iv_sender_avatar.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                    val avatarView = headerHolder.itemView.iv_sender_avatar
                    val translationY = max(0f, -nextHolder.itemView.top.toFloat())
                    avatarView.translationY = translationY
                } else {
                    headerHolder.itemView.iv_sender_avatar.translationY = 0f
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but its not working at all